# Why do we need to call local_bh_disabled() before calling the function conn_request()?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

I can't understand what is the role of the function `local_bh_disable()` which is called before the function `conn_request()` [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L5828). Does that mean that only one process can access this section at this point of time (some kind of lock)? I'm asking that because I want to delete some entries from the `ehash` table after calling `conn_request`, but I don't know if I must to do it inside this section or not.

```c
if (th->syn) {
    if (th->fin)
        goto discard;
    /* It is possible that we process SYN packets from backlog,
     * so we need to make sure to disable BH right there.
     */
    local_bh_disable();
    acceptable = icsk->icsk_af_ops->conn_request(sk, skb) >= 0;
    local_bh_enable();

    if (!acceptable)
        return 1;
    consume_skb(skb);
    return 0;
}
```

PS: From source code of Linux kernel 4.15

Comment: https://kernelnewbies.org/ might be a better place to ask

Comment: http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/kerneldevelopment/0672327201/ch07lev1sec6.html

Comment: I'm not kernel expert but had some work with it before. it's only my assumption but  since `tcp_rcv_state_process` called from both `tcp_v4_rcv` and `tcp_v6_rcv` it's required some kind of synchronization and from the function comment for `tcp_v4_rcv` `We have a potential double-lock case here, so even when doing backlog processing we use the BH locking scheme. This is because we cannot sleep with the original spinlock held.` we can assume that `local_bh_disable()` is used here instead of `spinlock` since this call can sleep.  NOTE!! THIS IS JUST MY GUESS! AND CANNOT BE CONSIDERED AS TRUTH.

Answer (score 0):

have you understood this question? According to the code comment, local_bh_disable should be called if SYN packets is from backlog, I think that's because backlog processing is in userspace, softirq's tcp_v4_rcv will push skb to backlog when sk->sk_lock.owned is owned by userspace, it can also ensure that backlog in userspace does not conflict with tcp_v4_rcv in softirq without local_bh_disable.   But conn_request will create synack timer, only local_bh_disable can be ensure that synack timer can be executed after conn_request. this is my guess too.

Comment: But I do not know why does syn skb can be put into backlog? if (sk->sk_state == TCP_LISTEN) {
  ret = tcp_v4_do_rcv(sk, skb);
  goto put_and_return;
 }   tcp_v4_do_rcv dose not put syn packet to backlog.

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=449809a66c1d0 , but I do not know why dccp syn skb processed in backlog